# Checking for fields not on SET clause on before update trigger on MySQL

Tags: mysql, trigger

I want to set a before update trigger that sets a column to a given value if an update query is done and that column has no new value on the set clause.

The table I'm using. (Sort of)

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS 'hex';
CREATE TABLE 'hex' (
    'id'    INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    'chunk' VARCHAR(45),
    'flag'  TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY ('id')
);
```

So, what I want to do is when `hex.chunk` gets a new value and flag doesn't, flag is set to 0.

e.g.

Current Dataset

```
id   chunk           flag
1    "Antelope"      0
2    "Barracuda"     1
3    "Capybara"      0
4    "Dolphin"       1
```

Operations and Expected Results

Case 1 `UPDATE hex SET chunk = "Antelope" WHERE id = 1;` doesn't update the `flag` since `chunk` doesn't get a new value.

Case 2 `UPDATE hex SET chunk = "Elephant" WHERE id = 2;` updates the `flag` to `0` since `chunk` changes its value and no data for flag is passed.

Case 3 `UPDATE hex SET chunk = "Capybara", flag = '1' WHERE id = 3;` `chunk` and `flag` updates as queried.

Case 4 `UPDATE hex SET chunk = "Ferrovax", flag = '0' WHERE id = 3` Same as case 3.

So, I've tried using this trigger but it doesn't seem to work the way I want it to work.

```
CREATE TRIGGER 'flag_the_hex'
BEFORE UPDATE ON 'hex'
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (NEW.flag IS NULL AND NEW.chunk != OLD.chunk)
    THEN
        SET NEW.flag = 0;
    END IF;
END
```

I think my main confusion here is **how NEW values in the columns not updated are represented in triggers**. If I update only the `chunk` column, how is the NEW value for `flag` represented? Null? Or does it just not exist yet?

Please keep in mind that there may be more columns in the table I'm using.

Thanks for reading.

EDIT: I asked this question over at StackOverflow and thought that may not be the appropriate place to ask this question. So, I asked this here and deleted it over there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`flag` will be what it had been before the `UPDATE` started.  Maybe it would feel 'right' to use `OLD.flag` instead of `NEW.flag`, at least in the `if`?

**Addenda**

`NEW.flag` contains the new value. `NEW.flag <=> OLD.flag` checks to see if it changed. I doubt if there is any way to see if it was set but not changed. (Note that I used the ["NULL-safe equal" operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to).)

Comment: Sorry, but nope.. Still doesn't work the way I want it to. I don't really care about the old value of the flag. I just want it to set to 0 if no value is passed. Is there anyway to know which values are set in the query?

Comment: Oh. I see. So, the cases I stated are not possible to recreate using only triggers. You may want to edit your answer to include your previous comment so I can select it as the answer. Thanks, by the way.

Comment: Comment folded in; deleting comment.